# Android hardware buttons position

Tags: android, android-hardware

Is it possible to know position of hardware settings button? I want to write an intro for my programm and show the user how to use it's features.

Comment: hardware settings? You mean the option-key right?

Comment: yes, sure. Sorry, do not know much English.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it is not. You'd try to check what device you are running on and then get position from your prepopulated database, but otherwise there's no way. Please note hardware buttons are deprecated since Honeycomb (and the good thing is that software buttons order is known and almost device independent).

Comment: This. Also the 3 remaining buttons (back, home, task switch) are system level controls that should have nothing to do with your app. Except for back of course, but you don't need to teach your users how to use it.
Your controls should be in the ActionBar or its overflow menu, where it is easy to show them.

Answer (score 2):

The ViewConfiguration class might help. It has a method **[hasPermanentMenuKey()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewConfiguration.html#hasPermanentMenuKey)**

```
public boolean hasPermanentMenuKey ()

Since: API Level 14 Report if the device has a permanent 
menu key available to the user.

Returns true if a permanent menu key is present, false otherwise.
```

But to know the exact position of the menu key **isn't possible**.  You could just find out if it exists or not, in hardware.

Comment: +1 for `hasPermanentMenuKey()`, yet API14 makes it quite useless for OP's task. It's rather to find out if you shall add menu button to your action bar or not (like i.e. Market app does)